# RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class TuserActivity is not accessible from class android.app.Instrumentation

Tags: android, firebase

First, I'm a beginner for android. I'm developing a simple login application by using firebase, when I run my code I faced this Runtime exception.i'm using phone number authentication, The application was installed successfully, but I can't go to TuserActivity can anyone tell me how to solve this?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{TuserActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class TuserActivity is not accessible from class android.app.Instrumentation

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public EditText emailId, passwd;
        Button btnSignUp;
        TextView signIn,txuser;
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            emailId = findViewById(R.id.ETemail);
            passwd = findViewById(R.id.ETpassword);
            btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
            signIn = findViewById(R.id.TVSignIn);
            txuser = findViewById(R.id.tuser);
            btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String emailID = emailId.getText().toString();
                    String paswd = passwd.getText().toString();
                    if (emailID.isEmpty()) {
                        emailId.setError("Enter your E-mail");
                        emailId.requestFocus();
                    } else if (paswd.isEmpty()) {
                        passwd.setError("Enter your password");
                        passwd.requestFocus();
                    } else if (emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!(emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty())) {
                        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, paswd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Task task) {

                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                            "SignUp unsuccessful: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_Login.class);
                    startActivity(I);
                }
            });

            txuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TuserActivity.class);
                    startActivity(I);

                }
            });
        }
}
```

manifest:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".Activity_Login"></activity>
>
>     <meta-data
>         android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
>         android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MapsActivity"></activity>
>
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".UserActivity" />
>     <activity android:name=".VerifyPhoneActivity" />
>     <activity android:name=".TuserActivity" />
> </application>
> ```

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest ?

Comment: yeah.. here it is.. i added..

Comment: thats a funky exception. How are you installing your app? (I'd do a manual uninstall for now, plus clear the caches in your AndroidStudio, and rebuild).

Comment: if you run it without the instrumentation, it works ?

Comment: i did both of your suggestion, but it's not working.

Comment: Please also add the content of your `TuserActivity` class. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 18):

It just happened to me.
I was forgetting to set my activity (in your case, TuserActivity) as public with the `public` modifier. It seems that Android can't access a java Activity that is not explicitly public. e.g:

```
public class TuserActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Also, if you're new to Android in 2020, then you really should consider starting with Kotlin.