# Android Application crashes as soon as connected to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Android App crashes as soon as I click a button, while it is connected to Firebase. I copied the same application in a new Project, without connecting it to Firebase and it didn't crashed. How can I avoid the crashing of the App
Here is my app gradle:

The Error I get in the Logcat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.paragleid_app/com.example.paragleid_app.Regestration}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void com.example.paragleid_app.Regestration.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2850)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void com.example.paragleid_app.Regestration.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2840)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

LoginActvity:

```
    theName = Name.getText().toString();
    thePassword = Passwort.getText().toString();

    Registieren.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openRegestration();
        }
    });

    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference myCoRef = db.collection("User");

            db.collection("Users")
                    .whereEqualTo("Password", thePassword) // task to query if name and Password matches
                    .whereEqualTo("name", theName)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                //QuerySnapshot result = task.getResult();
                                Toast toast = Toast. makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful", Toast. LENGTH_SHORT);
                                openVereinsUebersicht();

                            } else {
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login wasn't successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

As soon as this line comes to operation: the App crashes

```
public void openRegestration () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Regestration.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What's going on in  com.example.paragleid_app.Regestration?

Comment: @KristyWelsh I added some code, from a class in com.example.paragleid_app.Regestration

Comment: Where is this:  openRegestration () called?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325094/runtimeexception-java-lang-illegalaccessexception-class-tuseractivity-is-not-a)?

Comment: @KristyWelsh openRegestration() is called in the first method of the LoginActivity.